# How can I change which programs are listed in the context menus for files in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I'd like to know how to change some entries makes in 'second button list', that list of programs associated with a file icon.

Some I would like to remove and others I would like to put in.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the second button list ?

Comment: Nyamiou, I think he means the drop-down menu you get when you right-click a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the items in the Open With menu by

1. Right-clicking the file of the filetype you want to change. (I'm using an MP3 for my example.)
2. Choosing Properties from the drop-down menu.

   [image: Nautilus Right-click Menu]
3. Clicking the Open With tab.

   [image: Nautilus File Open With Tab]

You can add and remove Open With items there. The controls are fairly self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to modifying the list of available actions when you right click on a file in the Nautilus file browser. In which case try installing the *nautilus-actions* package. This allows you to create custom shortcuts for context menus (the menu, which appears when you right-click the mouse).

Install from the command line

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Or search for *nautilus actions* in the Ubuntu Software Center